# Error parsing XML : no element found

Tags: android, xml

When I tried building my application today I came past a problem called ***Error parsing XML : no element found*** I cant fix it. I don't know if it's an unclosed tag or something but I dont seem to get it.This is my code:

```
    <group>
        <item android:checkableBehavior="single"/>
        <item android:title="" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church1"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Χαράλαμπος" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church2"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Τίμιος Σταυρός" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church3"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Παναγία του Γιαννούλη" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church4"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Αγία Βαρβάρα" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church5"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Γεώργιος ο Καθολικός" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church6"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Επισκοπή" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church7"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Αγία Άννα" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church8"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιοι Θεώδοροι" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church9"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Νικόλαος" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church10"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Κήρυκος" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church11"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Στυλιανός" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church12"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιοι Δημήτριος και Γεώργιος του Κάστρου" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church13"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Ελευθέριος" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church14"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Μηνάς" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church15"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Αγία Μακρίνα" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church16"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Αγία Κυριακή" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church17"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Ταξιάρχης Μιχαήλ" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church18"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Ζαχαρίας" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church19"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Αγία Κρυφτή" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church20"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Ιωάννης Θεολόγος" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church21"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Σπυρίδων" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church22"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Νικόλαος" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church23"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιοι Ανάργυροι" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church24"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Κοίμηση της Αγίας Άννης" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church25"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Αγία Αικατερίνη" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church26"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Δημήτριος" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church27"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Κοίμησις Θεοτόκου" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church28"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Μεταμόρφωση του Σωτήρος" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church29"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Ταξιάρχης Μιχαήλ (2)" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church30"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Τίμιος Πρόδρομος" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church31"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Ευθύμιος" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church32"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Γεώργιος" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church33"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Στέφανος" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church34"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Αθανάσιος" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_church35"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Νικόλαος Μαυρίκας" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Extra">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Πληροφορίες" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Επικοινωνία"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
```

And this is a screenshot of the problem:
[Click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgG19.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change elements order

```
<Group> should be child of `<Menu>` item
```

Your code should be like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:title="item1"
        />
    <Group>
    <item  
        android:title="item1Group1"
        />
    <item 
        android:title="item2Group1"
        />
    </Group>
    <group>
        <item
            android:title="item1Group2"
            />
        <item
            android:title="item2Group2"
            />
    </group>
    <item
        android:title="item2"
        />
</menu>
```

***in your Case :***

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:title="Extra">
        <group>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Πληροφορίες" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Επικοινωνία"/>
        </group>
    </item>
</menu>
```

**YOU MUST DEFINE THE ROOT MENU ITEM AS :**

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

Comment: It still doesnt work, I added the group and now it has a problem with the <menu></menu> tag. Thats my code where the problem exists: http://pastie.org/10882734

Comment: @AndrewGiannoulis Show my update of the answer and let me know if it works or not